# How to calculate bubble sort's time complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was trying to understand the data structure and different algorithm, but then I got confused to measure the [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) time complexity.

```
for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); c++) {
  for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {
    if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For descending order use < */
    {
      swap       = array[d];
      array[d]   = array[d+1];
      array[d+1] = swap;
    }
  }
}
```

Now every [big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) tells the *best* case O(n), Avg case(n2) and Worst Case(n2). But when I see the code, found in first phase inner loop run n times and then in the second phase n - 1, and n - 2 and so on. That means in every iteration its value goes down.
For example, if I have a[] = {4, 2, 9, 5, 3, 6, 11}, so the total number of comparison will be -

```
1st Phase - 7 time
2nd phase - 6 time
3rd Phase - 5 time
4th Phase - 4 time
5th Phase - 3 time
6th Phase - 2 time
7th Phase - 1 time
```

so when I calculate the time it looks like = (7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1)  + 7 = 35, but the worst time complexity is n2 as per documentation.

How can I calculate the correct value?

Comment: `O(n^2)` very much does *not* mean that the total number of steps will exactly equal `n^2`.

Comment: To add to @AakashM, you first need to understand the meaning of `O(...)` notation. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's go through the cases for Big O for Bubble Sort

Case 1) O(n) (Best case)
This time complexity can occur if the array is already sorted, and that means that no swap occurred and only 1 iteration of n elements

Case 2) O(n^2) (Worst case)
The worst case is if the array is already sorted but in descending order. This means that in the first iteration it would have to look at n elements, then after that it would look n - 1 elements (since the biggest integer is at the end) and so on and so forth till 1 comparison occurs.
Big-O = n + n - 1 + n - 2 ... + 1 = (n*(n + 1))/2 = O(n^2)

In your example, it may not examine these many elements in each phase as the array is not in descending order.

Comment: As a definition Big Oh (O) notation denotes worst case scenario only, while Big Omega Ω(O) notation denotes best case scenario!

Comment: The O(n) variant of BubbleSort is the one that stops iterating when there's nothing else to sort. The code in this question always runs the inner loop approx. n^2/2 times, even thought it doesn't always swap. So this code is O(n^2) for all inputs.

Comment: Also, Big-O is not tied to best/worst case. Big-O means "upper-bound". Omega means "lower-bound". It makes sense to say that BubbleSort is Ω(n) and O(n^2) for all inputs, but it also makes sense to say that it's O(n) in the best case and even that it's Ω(n^2) in the worst case.

Answer (score 7):

So you've noticed that the total number of comparisons done is  (n - 1) + ... + 2 + 1.
This sum is equal to n * (n - 1) / 2 (see [Triangular Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)) which is equal to 0.5 n^2 - 0.5 n which is clearly O(n^2).

Answer (score 4):

It does comparison between two elements. So in
the first phase - n-1 comparison. I.e., 6

Second phase - n-2 comparisons. I.e, 5
and so on till 1.

And thus, sum = n(n-1)/2 i.e., O(n^2).

Answer (score 3):

***Best case***: This time complexity can occur if the array is already sorted. That means no swapping occurs and only 1 iteration of n elements will be there.

So time complexity is **O(n)**.

**Worst case**: This time complexity can occur if the array is already sorted but is descending order.

In **1st** iteration, number of comparison = **n-1** 
In **2nd** iteration, number of comparison = **n-2** 
**.......................................................................** 
**.......................................................................**
**.......................................................................**
In **(n-2)th** iteration, number of comparison = **2** 
In **(n-1)th** iteration, number of comparison = **1**

for n elements total number of iteration= **n-1** 
Total number of comparison **S = (n-1)+ (n-2) +........ +    2    +     1**
We can write this also           **S =        1 +       2 +   ........+(n-2) + (n-1)**
................................................................................................................................
                                          **2S =            n +       n + ......... +      n +          n**  .... [Adding both line] 
                                          **2S = n(n-1)** ..... [as total no of iteration = n-1] 
                                           **S = n(n-1)/2**  
In polynomial function, highest order of n is considered as time complexity. 
So, Time Complexity is **O(n^2)**

Answer (score 2):

`O(n^2) = n(n-1)/2` is the right one.

As in the above example of 5 elements.

```
5(5-1)/2 == 10.

5(5+1)/2 != 10.
```

Answer (score 1):

Explaining for the worst-case scenario here:

```
elements = raw_input("Enter comma-separated Elements: ")
elements = elements.split(',')
elements = map(int, elements)
length = len(elements)

for i in xrange(length - 1):
    print "Outer pass: ", i
    for j in xrange(length - i - 1):
        print "Inner pass: ", j
        if elements[j] > elements[j + 1]:
            elements[j + 1], elements[j] = elements[j], elements[j + 1]
        print "Elements: ", elements
print elements
```

Output:

Enter comma-separated Elements: 5,4,3,2,1

Outer pass:  0

Inner pass:  0

Elements: [4, 5, 3, 2, 1]

Inner pass:  1

Elements:  [4, 3, 5, 2, 1]

Inner pass:  2

Elements:  [4, 3, 2, 5, 1]

Inner pass:  3

Elements:  [4, 3, 2, 1, 5]

Outer pass:  1

Inner pass:  0

Elements:  [3, 4, 2, 1, 5]

Inner pass:  1

Elements:  [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]

Inner pass:  2

Elements:  [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

Outer pass:  2

Inner pass:  0

Elements:  [2, 3, 1, 4, 5]

Inner pass:  1

Elements:  [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]

Outer pass:  3

Inner pass:  0

Elements:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Thus, in the first iteration, all n elements are scanned. It would scan n - 1 elements in the next iteration. And so on for all the elements.

n + n - 1 + n - 2 ... + 1 = (n * (n + 1))/2 = O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

For n number of numbers, total number of comparisons done will be (n - 1) + ... + 2 + 1. This sum is equal to (n-1) * n / 2 (see Triangular Numbers) which equals to 0.5 n^2 - 0.5 n i.e. O(n^2)