# What is the time complexity of this bubble sort function?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o, bubble-sort

I wrote this bubble sort function but I am having a hard time figuring out the time complexity of it.

```
function bubbleSort(items) {  
    for (var i = items.length; i > 0; i--) {
      for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (items[j] > items[j + 1]) {
          var temp = items[j];
          items[j] = items[j + 1];
          items[j + 1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }

    return items;
}
```

I know that the outer loop has time complexity of O(n).  But what is the time complexity of the inner loop (since it goes through one less element of `items` on each pass) ?

Comment: google for "bubble sort complexity", to find references such as [this one in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Performance). Or search on SO, which turns up 375 results.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop is O(n). At the beginning it will execute n times, at the end 1 time. On average it will execute n/2 times. Constant factors don't matter, so that's O(n).

Together, the overall runtime is therefore O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

If you consider how many times inner loop is run, you may have a better idea:

```
1st run : N times, 
2nd run: N-1 times 
... 
Nth run: 1 time.
```

If you add them all

```
N + (N-1) + (N-2) + ... + 1 = [N * (N+1)]/2
```

times. That makes O(N^2). For more information, check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29556003

Comment: I don't understand. If that question/answer provides "more information", does not that make this question a duplicate?

Comment: @torazaburo You are right, since I couldn't find "mark as duplicate" option from mobile app, I put URL of the answer below. Thanks for the reminder btw.

Answer (score 1):

One way to calculate the time complexity of your algorithm is to note that the inner loop executes `i` iterations where `i` ranges from `n` down to 1 (where `n` is the length of the input). This means that we can do a summation to get the total number of steps in the algorithm:

```
n + (n-1) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1
```

This summation has a familiar closed formula:

```
n*(n+1) / 2
```

This formula is clearly `O(n^2)`.